# How to count the number of digits of a number in a print statement?

Tags: bc

In GNU bc, I can print a value using the `print` statement. Depending on the value and other parameters, more or less characters will actually be printed. How can I determine the number of characters, that will be printed, such that I can print a table of numbers in nice columns?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `length` function in GNU bc for this.

```
length(1234567)
7
```

It gets a bit trickier though because

```
length(-123.4567)
7
```

and if you're doing floating point arithmetic bc will print trailing zeros according to your scale:

```
 scale = 7
 -123.4567/1
 -123.4567000
```

but `length` will account for this. So we just need to count the negative sign and decimal point. For a floating point input `n`,

```
define printedlength (n) {
  auto l
  l = length(n)
  if (n < 0) l += 1 # negative sign 
  return l+1 # decimal point
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the number of characters being printed to some extent with the special variable `scale`, which determines the number of digits after the decimal point – but it only changes the number of digits stored after calculations. For example:

```c
scale = 3
var = 0.12345
var     /* Still shows five digits */
.12345
var/1   /* Now just three digits */
.123
```

But at least it doesn't just truncate, but also add padding:

```c
var = 0.12
var
.12
var/1
.120
```

If you want to use this in a script, you probably want to assign the output of the division by one to the variable itself:

```c
var /= var/1
print var
```

For anything more refined than this, I'd assign the output of bc to shell variables and use `printf` for formatting.